# Why inner join too slow?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-server-ce, ms-access-2010

I've tested both Microsoft Access and Microsoft SQL Compact with ADODB.

I have a table tblCustomer for storing customer information

```
tblCustomer structure
--------------------
ID  Name  Email        Something...
1   ABC   ABC@ABC.com  Something....
```

And a tblTag for categories customer into many types . For example rich customer: tag id = 1 , debt customer : tag id  =2 . Each customer can have one or both tag.

```
tblTag structure
--------------------
ID  TagID  CustomerID
1   1      1
2   2      1
```

And then i already added index for column ID, TagID, CustomerID for those table.

But when i using this query for getting all customer that are rich. The query take me 8000ms with total 170.000 records in tblCustomer.

```
Select * from tblCustomer INNER JOIN tblTag on
tblTag.CustomerID=tblCustomer.ID where tblTag.TagID=1
```

If i run only `Select * from tblCustomer` , it's only take me 3000 ms. It's even faster when i get all table. Inner join is not running as my expected. And 8000 ms is too slow with me when the customer can grow up to 1.000.000 record and i don't want my program stun a minute for each time run this query. So may be i've wrong when create a table Tag? Should i bring the tag into tblCustomer as a column like Rich (bit) or Debt (bit) ?

Comment: Do you have an index on tblTage, where the first index column is CustomerID? That is not clear from your description.

Comment: Yes, the first index column is CustomerID, nothing change

Answer (score 0):

For some cases, try to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Hopefully, it helps!

Comment: It's even make the program stun for a minute :(

Comment: I usually use LEFT JOIN to lower the latency. Since you said Select * from tblCustomer took you 3000ms, that's quite normal to have 5000+ms for joining the table. Is the JEFT JOIN quite faster than INNER JOIN in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Index all your tables properly.  Cluster Index the field that is most important (seems like that woul dbe CustomerID in tblTag and ID in tblCustomer), and put a regular index on TagID in tblTag.